# XCode: Reload New View For Instance of View Controller 

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

So I have my app delegate handling some fblogin stuff and when it comes back from logging in my view controllers outlets don't seem to be connected. I figure its because the AppDelegate is initializing a new view controller without setting a nib name...but I don't know how to do that with storyboard. Help!

Please keep it simple, I'm still kinda new.

Also, let me know what code I can provide to help.

**MORE INFO:**

I figured I needed to add more info to help figure this out. OK, so from inside my view controller, I create an instance of the app delegate. The app delegate contains an instance of a facebook object. From the view controller I call `[[appDelegateInst facebook] authorize:permissions];` which initiates the authorization dialog for facebook (in a new window). The app delegate instance of facebook is initialized like so:

```
 vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"309362365798188" andDelegate:vc];
```

So, the view controller tells the app delegate instance to go ahead and authorize (login) its instance of facebook. The delegate for that instance of facebook is the viewcontroller instance (vc). When the auth call hands control back to the app, the delegate method `fbDidLogin()` is called (which is inside the viewcontroller class). In that method, I have to manually call viewDidLoad because all of my instance variables are now null ...I may have just answered my own question ..I created an instance of viewcontroller but never loaded the view..so when I return I'm now 'inside' the appdelegate view controller instance but trying to connect to the view of the previous instance which is now on the page..is that right? If so, how do I fix it :)

-Josh

Answer (score 0):

Storyboards and nibs (.xib) are mostly mutually exclusive.  The normal thing for a storyboard is that some controller is marked as the initial one and it's presented semi-magically :) at the beginning.  Then, that controller's viewDidLoad: method is called as part of app startup and, at that point, your outlets should be valid.

Comment: Hmmmn. Then I'm just confused and am at a loss in terms of how to debug. When I NSLog my UITableView for example (pre-login) it says <UITableView: 0x80acc00; ..etc.. but when it comes back from the login, and viewDidLoad is called ..the log returns NULL. Any ideas?..maybe my interface isn't being loaded for some reason? Can I do that manually somehow?

Comment: If you comment out the "lgging in" stuff, are the outlets OK in viewDidLoad?  (That would verify whether the storyboard connections are set correctly.)  Also, is the login going to a new view controller and, if so, is it part of the storyboard?

Comment: Yea everything works fine before the login..I can change button texts and throw stuff in the table. I'm not exactly sure how the login works..it opens a browser or something then returns..not part of the story board...its just part of the facebook sdk api... and then I think it hands control back to the app.

Comment: Also, I see you're from Toronto, any chance you do private consulting (aka tutoring)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Hooray for me! So instead of using a new instance of the view controller in my appdelegate I implemented this:

```
-(void) doFBLoginStuff:(id)oldView
{
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"309362365798188" andDelegate:oldView];
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}
```

And called that from my original view controller with [appDelegateInst doFBLoginStuff:self];

Comment: Congratulations!  :-)  (I wasn't going to be any help with anything specific to Facebook.)